# Access Eventcreate parameter

Tags: windows, batch-file, events

I have a problem.
I create a Windows Event with the command:

```
EVENTCREATE /T INFORMATION /L APPLICATION /so BlahBlahBlah /ID 999 /D "%1 %2"
```

this event will trigger a .bat file. Is it possible to access the two parameter from the description (after the /D) in the .bat file?

Edit:
[image]

thank you,
Blue

Comment: modify your trigger OR let the batch read he eventlog with psloglist for example Or  every way a batch might handle inter proces communication.

Comment: how shall i modify my trigger?

Comment: Only you know your setup. See [eventtriggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb490901.aspx)
And there: `/tk   TaskName   : Specifies the task/command/line to execute when the event trigger conditions are met. `

Comment: I added my setup on the top. In the blah.bat I want to echo the description from the the EVENTCREATE order (whatever %1 and %2 contains)

Comment: NO that is what pushes the trigger. This might help you [event-log-trigger-include-event-data](https://vijredblog.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/task-scheduler-event-log-trigger-include-event-data-in-mail/) even if a bit different.